# Minecraft Failed To Bind Port

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

I made a server and used my IPv4 address for the IP. I decided to scratch that server and make a Bukkit server so I can use plugins. I tried to use my IPv4 address which I used for my other server but I keep getting the message `[17:31:15 WARN]: ****FAILED TO BIND TO PORT!`

Is there any thing I can do to get a new address to use or is there a way to delete the old server? Do I need to use a different computer? Please help! I've don't know how to fix this problem. If you have any suggestions please tell me and I'll give it a try.

Comment: What do you mean by "delete the old server"? As long as you don't run minecraft_server.xyz.jar there is no server. Make sure the other server is shut down, using either the /stop command or by killing all java/javaw processes.

Answer (score 3):

Go to your server.properties and make sure "server.ip=" is empty.

> server-ip=

Make sure the port you are trying to use for the server isn't being used elsewhere.

Comment: I remember doing that on my other server and I did it to mine a while back but it still doesn't work.

Comment: So your still having the problem?

Comment: Yes, do I have to use a different computer? Or is there another IP I can use?

Comment: You can use the same computer, your IP will always be the same. Click [here](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=whats+my+ip) to find out your public IP, this is what you use to join the server.

Comment: if you want to run two servers, on the other hand, you need to change the port -> find this line in the server.properties server-port=25565 and change it to a different number like 25566

Answer (score 0):

MAC FIX FOR LOCALHOST:

1. Open "Activity Monitor"
2. Search "Java"
3. Force Quit "Java"
4. Start Server

This usually fixes the issue. Hope it helps for you.